# Does Destiny's Strike kiho override the defence or full defence rule about making an attack?

Tags: l5r-4e

Does Destiny's Strike kiho override the defence or full defence rule about making an attack?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the beginning:

> **Destiny's Strike (Martial/Fire 4)**
>
> While this Kiho is active, whenever you are struck by a melee attack from an opponent, you may immediately make a counterattack in the form of a single unarmed attack.  If you have not taken your Turn yet this round, this counts as your Turn.  If you have taken your Turn, this is a Free Action instead.  This counterattack ignores and wound penalties suffered as a result of the attack to which it is responding.  This Kiho lasts until the end of the Skirmish.

Kiho activation itself is a simple, non-attack action so it can be activated as part of a Defense (Air) Turn.  Full Defense (Water) is a Complex Action, which takes Full Defense off of the list for starters.

The only restriction I can determine, is that if you hit by an attack with a higher initiative than yours, then you have used your Turn before your initiative.  Since this is part of your last turn, it depends on what stance you were in during activation.  Defense specifically says you cannot attack.  Strangely, Full Defense (by RAW, not spirit) does not explicitly state this restriction.  It is a complex action already, and states you may take Free Actions, which they likely didn't consider could be an attack unless higher level anyway.  So going only with RAW, you can counter with this kiho since it is a free action.

I would talk to your GM, but if you are in Defense stance, and your turn hasn't arrived to change it, then you can't counter.  Otherwise, it seems to trigger normally.